# Powerpoint VBA - ExtractAssociatedIcon - Error 424. Object required

Tags: vba

I have inserted in a slide (on Powerpoint) a listview control.

I tried to display all files and folders + icons, using this code:

```
Dim fso, objFolder, objFile, strTemp
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder("c:\")
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    ImageList21.Images.Add Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(objFile.Name)
    ListView31.Items.Add objFile.Name, ImageList21.Images.Count - 1
Next
```

I added the right reference to my project, but, this error occurs:
`Run-time error 424. Object required.`

Comment: `ExtractAssociatedIcon` is a .NET method, and you're using VBA, so you'll need to find an alternative method which will work with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

"ExtractAssociatedIcon is a .NET method, and you're using VBA, so you'll need to find an alternative method which will work with VBA." [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams)

Comment: Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.